# The number of ways in which $11^{11}$ can be written as a product of $3$ factors

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways in which $11^{11}$ can be written as a product of $3$ factors

Attempt:writting $11^{11} = a\times b \times c = 11^{x}\times 11^{y}\times 11^{z} = 11^{x+y+z}$

so $x+y+z = 11$ and $x,y,z\geq 0$ and $x,y,z$ all are integer

now one pair is $(2,3,6)$ similarly other pairs is $(0,0,11),(1,1,9),.....$

could some help me how to get all ordered pairs, thanks

Comment: This is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  You are looking for weak compositions of three numbers that sum to $11$.  Have you heard of this?  The Wikipedia page explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have to select two $1$'s from horizontal string of thirteen $1$'s.

$$\underbrace{1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1}_{11 ~\text{times}}$$

If you have to find the number of sloutions of $x+y+z=11$, it is similar to selecting any two $1$'s in the string of $1$'s.Since it would divide all the one $1$'s into three parts (left,middle and right) giving you the value of $x,y,z$.For example ;

$$\underbrace{~1~~~1~}_{2}~~\boxed{1}~~\underbrace{ 1~~~1~~~1~~~1}_{4}~~\boxed1~~\underbrace{1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1}_{5}$$

Selecting $1$'s in this way gives you $x=2,y=4,z=5$.

$$\underbrace{}_{0}~~\boxed1~~~\underbrace{}_{0}~~\boxed1~~\underbrace{1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1~~~1}_{11}$$

Selecting $1$'s in this way gives you $x=0,y=0,z=11$.

Total number of ways of selecting two $1$'s :

$$\binom{13}{2}=78$$

It would be better if you remember a formula for solving this type of questions :

Number of ways for selecting $x_i$'s such that

$$x_1+x_2+x_3 \dots x_r=n ~~~\text{is}~~ \binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$$

Where each $x_i \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

```
int z, y, x, sum = 0;
    for (z = 11; z >= 0; z -= 1)
        for (y = 11; y >= 0; y -= 1)
            for (x = 11; x >= 0; x -= 1)
                if (x + y + z == 11)
                    sum += 1;
    System.out.println(sum);
```

by a brute force algorithm i got the answer : $78$ 
for all permutation which means that (0,11,0) and (0,0,11) and (11,0,0) are considered three distinct answers, if you don't want permutation the answer is $16$

```
int z, y, x, sum = 0;
    for (z = 11; z >= 0; z -= 1)
        for (y = z; y >= 0; y -= 1)
            for (x = y; x >= 0; x -= 1)
                if (x + y + z == 11)
                    sum += 1;
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: also could by solved by stars and bars, since there is 11 stars and 2 bars you have 13 item and 2 bars to be placed in all arrangements which is $\binom{13}{2}=78$

Comment: Which algorithm would one use to count unique combinations (as in your second code snippet)?